# Troubleshooting a code that is supposed to display 1 if Mean = Mode and 0 if it does not

Tags: javascript, arrays, mean, mode

I am a novice coder and I am trying to write a code that returns 1 if the mean is equal to the mode and 0 if it is not. So far the code I have written is only returning 0, even if it is supposed to be 1. Any help or tips in pin pointing where I went wrong will be greatly appreciated!

```
function ArrayChallenge(arr) { 
let sum = 0
let totalNum = arr.length
let mean = sum/totalNum
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > 0) {
    sum+= arr[i]
  }
}

const numList = {}
arr.forEach(elem => numList[elem] = numList[elem] + 1 || 1)
let mode = []
let numMax = 0
for (const key in numList) {
  if(numList[key] > numMax) {
    mode = [Number(key)]
    numMax = numList[key]
  } else if (numList[key] === numMax) {
    mode.push(Number(key))
  }
}
if (mode.length === Object.keys(numList). length) mode = []
if (mean === mode) {
  return 1
} else return 0
}
```

Comment: Mode seems to be an array, while mean is a number. So they can never be equal

Comment: Debug tip: what *are* the values that you think should be equal?

Answer (score 1):

`let mean = sum/totalNum` should be after the for loop in order for `sum` to be populated.

```
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {sum+= arr[i]}
}
let mean = sum/totalNum
```

When you are checking for return 1 or 0 respectively there is a fault comparison,
because `mean` is a number and `mode` is an array. So by adding **mode.length** you are geting the actual length (number) of the array and now you can compare it.

```
if (mean === mode.length) {
  return 1
} else return 0
}
```

**RESULTS:**
According your code, the behaviour of test data will be:

```
//ArrayChallenge([10,10,10]) -> 0
//ArrayChallenge([0,0,0]) -> 1
```

Make a note that the above results are taken assuming you want to check mode's length. It will be nice if you describe the problem with more information.